# the web service does not interprete the php code

Tags: php, xampp

I installed XAMPP and tried to run some php in localhost. However when I open the php file with the browser it does not show the result and it only show the code of the file. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your code and URL so others can help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too obvious but, how exactly are you opening the file? Are you double clicking the file from the htdocs folder? If yes, then is not processed by the webserver. Try giving the actual URL of the file in the browser' address bar. 
If not, code and some more info about your setup will help.

Comment: I’m able to fix the problem. It was my bad not installing apache and mysql just start them